# Why does Server Side Blazor's <AuthorizeView> not authorize on re-render

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, windows-authentication, blazor-server-side

I am trying to set up a simple Blazor project using Windows Authentication as a proof of concept and I am mis-informed with the capabilities of Blazor or I have misunderstood what I have read up until now.

I have created a Blazor server project using Windows Authentication and I am trying to restrict content based on user groups that users are assigned to inside Active Directory.

The problem I find myself facing is that my understanding of `AuthorizeView` allows you to restrict access based on roles and policies. However the first time the app loads the `AuthorizeView` shows the correct "Authorized" content but less than a second after the app re-renders and displays the "NotAuthorized" content.

Here is my start up with the Policies set up.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();

            services.AddAuthorization(config =>
            {
                config.AddPolicy("IsDeveloper", policy => policy.RequireRole("UserGroup_DEVELOPERS"));
                config.AddPolicy("IsDeveloperAdmin", policy => policy.RequireRole("UserGroup_DEVELOPERADMINS"));
            });

            services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
```

And this is the modified Index.razor file to show the content

```
@page "/"
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<AuthorizeView Policy="IsDeveloperAdmin">
    <Authorized>
        <p>You can only see this if you are a developer admin!!!</p>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <p>You are not a dev admin</p>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
<AuthorizeView><p>Hello world</p></AuthorizeView>
<AuthorizeView Policy="IsDeveloper">
    <Authorized>
        <p>You can only see this if you are a developer!!!</p>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <p>You are not a dev</p>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

And here is the result:
[image: Slowed down to show the change from Authorised to non authorised]

I have been over the Microsoft docs so if anyone can share a link to a resource and perhaps an insight to help me understand I would really appreciate it.

**UPDATE**

It seems to be a specific machine issue. The code above works on a different development machine. It also works when deployed to an IIS server. I have updated VS to the latest version with no luck.

When running the app in Visual Studio (2019) Edge Chronium and Google Chrome, both browsers do the authorisation on load then fail authorisation a split second later. However in IE11 the app authorises as expected.